# QTMovieView not in pallet

Tags: interface-builder, qtkit

I am trying to follow the [QTKit tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationTutorial/BuildingaSimpleMediaPlayerApplication/BuildingaSimpleMediaPlayerApplication.html). I add and include the QTKit framework and .h file. I create the QTMovie property. Then in IB I am supposed to drag out the QTMovieView from the library but it isn't there. If I go to the Classes tab, I can find it. However, when I drag it out, it doesn't have the attributes to set like movie source or anything...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the plugin in the prefs. The plugin was in the framework folder.